# How to add values ​and save them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the script, its logic is this: when I collect some objects in my game, they are added and saved in a UI in numerical value and then when I play again it will add to the previous one.
But the problem is that if I start another game, the previous value is not saved, and there is also no sum of the two values, thanks for the help.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject YellowSquare;
    private int currentScore;
    private int totalScoreSave;

    void Start() 
    {      
        totalScoreSave = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore"); 
        YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();

        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("lastScore"))
        {
            YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();
            GameController.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore");
        }
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore"));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();
        totalScoreSave++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lastScore", totalScoreSave);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call [save](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject YellowSquare;
    private int currentScore;
    private int totalScoreSave;

    void Start() 
    {      
        totalScoreSave = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore"); 
        YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();

        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("lastScore"))
        {
            YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();
            GameController.score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore");
        }
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lastScore"));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        YellowSquare.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameController.score.ToString();
        totalScoreSave++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lastScore", totalScoreSave);
        PlayerPrefs.Save(); // you need to save it, but i suggest you move this to the follow
    }
}
```